# "close to suicidal" instead of "close to suicide"

Tags: word-usage, parts-of-speech

> Repeating it tonight in front of Death Eaters who either witnessed or heard about the first occasion was **close to suicidal**!"
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I am wondering why it's "close to suicidal" instead of "close to suicide"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Suicide* is an activity someone does.  You can say "close to suicide" to mean someome is soon going to kill himself/herself.

*Suicidal* is something that someone *is*, and it usually means someone no longer cares if they live or die, therefore he/she acts reckless.  It can also mean "considering suicide" but doesn't necessarily mean a person is about to kill themselves in the next moment.

A very reckless activity, one that has no regard for any consequences, can figuratively be described as *suicidal*.